# python popen, stdout shows in strace, but not in popen.stdout.read()

Tags: python-3.x, popen, blocking

I have the below python script that I'm using to attempt to read from a program that doesn't have proper newlines for everything.  This allows reads without worrying about blocking reads.  However, because I don't know enough about Threading, I suspect that's where my problem lies.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import os
import time
from threading import Thread
import queue


class NonBlockingStreamReader:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        """
        :param stream: the stream to read from.  Usually stdout or stderr.
        """
        self._s = stream
        self._q = queue.Queue()

        def _populate_queue(_stream, _queue):
            """Collect lines from 'stream' and put them in 'queue'"""
            while True:
                _char = _stream.read(1)
                if _char:
                    _queue.put(_char)
                else:
                    raise UnexpectedEndOfStream

        self._t = Thread(
            target=_populate_queue,
            args=(
                self._s,
                self._q
            )
        )
        self._t.daemon = True
        self._t.start() # Start collecting characters from the stream

    def readchar(self, timeout=None):
        try:
            _tmp = self._q.get(block=timeout is not None, timeout=timeout)
            return _tmp
        except queue.Empty:
            return None


class UnexpectedEndOfStream(Exception):
    pass


def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split('strace -o /home/arts/dlm/trace_output.txt stdbuf -o0 /home/arts/dlm/test'),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    nbsr = NonBlockingStreamReader(proc.stdout)

    _data = b''
    while True:
        _char = nbsr.readchar(0.1)
        if not _char:
            break
        else:
            _data += _char
    print(_data.decode())

    proc.stdin.write(b'12345\n')

    _data = b''
    while True:
        _char = nbsr.readchar(5)
        if not _char:
            break
        else:
            _data += _char
    print(_data.decode())
    print('Annnnd done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the expected output of the `test` program:

```
Line 1 test
Line 2 test
Line 3 input: 12345      <--- input from user
Line 4 test: 12345
```

Here's the strace output:

```
write(1, "Line 1 test", 11)             = 11
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "Line 2 test", 11)             = 11
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "Line 3 input: ", 14)          = 14
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb76716d000
read(0, "12345\n", 4096)                = 6
write(1, "Line 4 test: 12345\n\n", 20)  = 20
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

This shows (to me at least) that the application IS providing the requested output.  `read(0, "12345\n", 4096)` shows the `proc.stdin.write(b'12345\n')` unless I'm missing something.  The next line shows it reading back out the output that I expect.  However, the REAL output is:

```
Line 1 test
Line 2 test
Line 3 input:

Annnnd done.
```

If I put some print statements after `_char = _stream.read(1)`, it shows nothing.  If I add them in the `readchar` function, then it shows `None`.

Something is breaking stdout, so wherever it's going, it's not going to the pipe.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your second read loop:

- It's breaking on empty `_data` instead of `_char`, and `_data` is set to `b''` at the top of the loop, so it will always exit without writing anything to `_data`.
- It breaks as soon as the reader's buffer is empty, which may or may not be after the entire output of the child process has been written or read, depending on the timing of the processes and threads involved.

You'll probably want to set an EOF flag in the reader instead of raising `UnexpectedEndOfStream` there and then base your loop on that (or rather, on a derived condition based on that flag being set and the queue being empty).

Comment: THANK YOU!  Yes, I noticed that as well and should have provided that in my self-answer, but alas, I did not!  For that, you get the right answer.  Also, excellent idea on the EOF catch.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Needed `bufsize=0` as an arg to `Popen`.